# Open weather default app with Linking API?

Tags: react-native

I'm would like to open the default app of weather application. I don't know if it's possible on iOS and Android in the same time.

Thanks you.

I think using Linking API is the best solution, but I don't know the url.

Comment: You want to know if using the linking API is the best solution or not?  And also you want to know the url for that API?

Comment: Yes, is there other solution ? If yes, wich one is the best ? And yes, I would like to know the url of the weather default, or a website wich list all the url for default alarm, browser, and everything because I couldn't find it

Comment: I don't know the answer :).  I wanted to clarify the question for others to see. Somehow, you are not getting enough attention. Let me help you out.

Comment: Thanks you a lot Jin Lee for the bounties ! I think it helped a lot !

Comment: My pleasure! Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Linking API to open any app in React Native. Now to open an app you need to use [Deep liking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking). With Deep Linking you have two options, open the app with URL Scheme or Universal Links.

While URL schemes are a well-known way of having deep linking, Universal links are the new way Apple has implemented to easily connect your webpage and your app under the same link.

**URL Scheme**

Examples:

- [maps://something](https://#)
- [twitter://something](https://#)
- [facebook://something](https://#)

[image]

**Universal Links**

[image]

Shows up on your website when something like this:

[image]
[image]

So all that to understand that are able to use Linking to open apps, how:

```js
import { Linking, Button } from 'react-native';

export default () => (
  <Button title="Open on Maps" onPress={() => Linking.openURL('maps://...')}>
)
```

Here are the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) for deep linking. As you see they have the docs for many of their apps (Facetime, Maps, iTunes, ...) but any documentation available for their **Wheater** app.

> There is not a default **Wheater app**, and there isn't any way to change/set another Weather app.

### Conclusion

You can open apps using **Linking** from React Native, but not a default Weather app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot. I will find a way for my meteo. But Linking was succefuly added in my app. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Apple weather app on iOS by opening the following URL:

https://weather.apple.com/?lat=37.33185&long-0122.02950

The URL will give a 403 error when open on macOS but at least on iOS 16.4 it will act as a Universal Link and open the weather app.

Comment: On the web that URL won't 403 if you include a city arg. Like this: https://weather.apple.com/?city=Boston&lat=42.3226734&lng=-71.0924375